# Is a synchronous operation (e.g., stringFromURL) subject to preemption by other threads?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I'm still trying to get my head around using background threads to fetch data. I don't want my thread to die when the called method ends, so it looks like an asymchronous operation in a background thread would be the wrong way to go. But it only makes sense to use a synchronous fetch if that fetch can be preempted so the main run loop can execute while waiting for data from the server.

Can someone clear this up for me? I want to understand it better, even if you might recommend using a networking library to hide all of this complication.

Comment: Why don't you want your thread to die when the method call ends?

Comment: I need to handle the results of the operation and do clean-up. So a completion method or completion block needs to be used when doing it asynchronously. If I do it synchronously, I can just put the completion code in-line. I can do this within a synchronous operation, but I am trying to understand how to make this happen when I have explicit separate completion methods.

Comment: If you are using network calls, can't you just use the NSURLConnection delegate methods? (like [connection:didReceiveData]) Failing that, I suppose you could a method that performs both operation you want synchronously and the clean up for it and run that on a seperate thread using performSelectorInBackground:

Comment: I currently use NSURLConnection and its delegate methods. I am scaling the application, though, and trying to understand the alternatives I have. I was aware of the performSelectorInBackground method, but hadn't given it any thought until you mentioned it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Main thread certainly executed during synchronous methods on other threads, moreover it can suspend executing methods on background threads when it need maximum performance e.g. while scrolling.
2. Asynchronous methods are more preferable because they give more control over you operation. And they can be called both from main thread or background thread.
3. Consider also using GCD and operation queues, see [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH1-SW1) for reference.

Comment: I started reading the Concurrency Programming Guide. It starting to get a little clearer what the possibilities are. I have seen some tutorials on GCD with NSOperations, and it wasn't clear to me. After I have studied this, I'll revisit your answer.